# How does strength affect a Brown Bear's bite damage?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I'm looking at the stats for a [Brown Bear](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/bearBrown.htm) and trying to figure out how to advance them (for a druid animal companion).  All of the derived stats make sense to me except for the Bite damage - why is this 2d6+4 and not 2d6+8?

Basically I'm wondering if the full strength bonus is being applied to bite damage or not, so that I can figure out how the damage changes as the animal's strength increases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bite is a [secondary natural weapon](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#naturalWeapons), as it shows up in the full attack but not in the attack line of the stat block.

> When a creature has more than one natural weapon, one of them (or
>   sometimes a pair or set of them) is the primary weapon. All the
>   creature’s remaining natural weapons are secondary.
>
> The primary weapon is given in the creature’s Attack entry, and the
>   primary weapon or weapons is given first in the creature’s Full Attack
>   entry. A creature’s primary natural weapon is its most effective
>   natural attack, usually by virtue of the creature’s physiology,
>   training, or innate talent with the weapon. An attack with a primary
>   natural weapon uses the creature’s full attack bonus. Attacks with
>   secondary natural weapons are less effective and are made with a -5
>   penalty on the attack roll, no matter how many there are. (Creatures
>   with the Multiattack feat take only a -2 penalty on secondary
>   attacks.) This penalty applies even when the creature makes a single
>   attack with the secondary weapon as part of the attack action or as an
>   attack of opportunity.

[Secondary natural weapons get half strength bonus](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/intro.htm):

> A creature’s primary attack damage includes its full Strength modifier
>   (1½ times its Strength bonus if the attack is with the creature’s sole
>   natural weapon) and is given first. Secondary attacks add only ½ the
>   creature’s Strength bonus and are given second in the parentheses.

Comment: Ah, "secondary" was the search keyword I was missing out on....